# How do I code "default placeholder text" of a UITextField in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using the following code to remove the placeholder text when a **UITextField** is clicked.

```
 (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}

 (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = @"MyPlaceholderText";
}
```

I have assigned the placeholder text in the Attributes inspector, but each text field has a unique placeholder.

What should I use instead of the string "MyPlaceholderText" to return to the default placeholder text I've already set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, you can save the default placeholder from the Storyboard into a property and then set it in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.defaultPlaceholder = textField.placeholder;
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = self.defaultPlaceholder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have 3 textfields.
       myTextField1, myTextField2, myTextField3;

Set tagValues of all 3 as

```
 myTextField1.tag = 1;
 myTextField2.tag = 2;
 myTextField3.tag = 3;
```

now in the method-

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 if(textField.tag == 1){
textField.placeholder = @"MyPlaceholderText1";   //custom placeholders
}

else if (textField.tag == 2){
 textField.placeholder = @"MyPlaceholderText2"; //custom placeholders
 }

else if (textField.tag == 3){
 textField.placeholder = @"MyPlaceholderText3"; //custom placeholders
 }
```